# Outlook 2013 VSTO - Get calendar selected range + callback

Tags: .net, calendar, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

How can I retrieve the displayed date range in an Outlook Calendar? For example, when I open the week view of the current week, I need to know in code that the current calendar displays the range from 2015-09-21 to 2015-09-27.

Let's assume I have a reference to the calendar as a `MAPIFolder` object. I found out that this object has a `CurrentView` member with several promising properties. But `DisplayedDates` contains no items, `Filter` is empty and `SelectedEndTime` / `SelectedStartTime` both points to 4501-01-01, i.e. no date set. So what am I doing wrong? And yes, at the time of evaluating this object, the calendar view in Outlook is open and active.

Second question: After it is possible to get the current display range, is there a callback or event which I can consume that is fired when the display range changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Explorer class, not folder. To obtain a [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864185.aspx) object for the view of the current [Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860356.aspx), use Explorer.CurrentView instead of the CurrentView property of the current Folder object returned by Explorer.CurrentFolder.

Here is what MSDN states:

The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419.aspx) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

> After it is possible to get the current display range, is there a callback or event which I can consume that is fired when the display range changes?

No, the Outlook object model doesn't provide such events. However, you may try to handle the [BeforeViewSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865397.aspx) event of the Explorer class which is fired before the explorer changes to a new view, either as a result of user action or through program code.